# Multiple author for an extension module

Tags: extension, gsoc, modules

Is it possible to have multiple author for a module extension? I'm extending last year's GSoC project. So, I need to have two author names for the module.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several maintainers, as for the authorship, it's a single one indeed (top of my head) and it's customary to keep the initial one and explain the documentation (eg. README.md) that you are taking over.

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hmm. Currently author too is added as `<maintainer><author ..><email..></maintainer>`. I tried adding both, adding two author inside maintainer and adding two maintainer. Neither worked.

Comment: How do you add multiple maintainers?